# How to use different styles in joomla by creating duplicate templates in joomla3.X?

Tags: joomla, sass, joomla3.0

I want to make different styles for different pages and by different styles I mean different scss in joomla3.x.
What I have tried and what problems I have faced each time:

**1) Creating duplicate template**

I created duplicate template from an existing template say **masterbootstrap** and tried to edit the scss. The problem I faced in this case was that the change occur in both templates (original and duplicate)

**2) Creating a copy of template**

I created a copy of existing template say **masterbootstrap** and tried to edit the scss. The problem I faced in this case was that despite I made changes to the scss and turned on the sass compilation, on the front page I received the message:

> No scss files were modified

I am new to joomla, I have searched the internet and was not able to find a solution, so I decided to post it here.

Comment: See https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/5399/120 for some better methods than duplicating the template.